# Differential graded modules and the Serre-Swan theorem

Tags: vector-bundles, differential-graded-algebras, cw-complexes

I am thinking about how [connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(mathematics)) combine with a modification of the [Serre-Swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem) theorem, which relates vector bundles to projective modules.

If $E \rightarrow B$ is a vector bundle, or even just any map of CW-complexes, then we get a map $E \rightarrow B \times E$, producing an action of DGAs $C^*(E) \otimes C^*(B) \rightarrow C^*(E)$. Examination of the relationship between the differential and the grading reveals a similar modified Liebnitz principal in the definition of [DGM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10127.pdf) (differential graded module) and connection. Further, the connection thus defined is flat because of how dd=0.

I want to modify the Serre-Swan theorem to relate differential graded modules and vector bundles with a flat connection. I'm not positive but the "projective" requirement might be removed, with the theorem set up to work modulo homotopy.

Any space over a CW-complex X produces a differential graded module, which is as mentioned a similar object to a vector bundle with flat connection.

DGMs are a "wellspring" of flat connections, which I want to function in tandem with the modified Serre-Swan to produce them all. Or in other words I was hoping that a large class of vector bundles with flat connection arose as DGMs of the cocomplex of a CW-complex.

It would be especially nice if the duality extended to DGMs and an overcategory of CW-complexes with a modified version of connections made to work with spaces.